# Geektool and returning Applescript

Tags: applescript, return, geektool

I have an Applescript script that is set to repeat every 10 seconds with Geektool.

I have returns at the end of each handler that let me know what's going on, but that affords me little chance to see mid-script what exactly is happening.

So what I'm asking is if there's a command in Applescript like return but will not halt the script?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
display dialog "This is what's going on" giving up after 1
```

or

```
    tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set xxx to "This is what's going on"
    do script "echo " & quoted form of xxx in window 1
    delay 2
    do script "echo " & quoted form of xxx in window 1
end tell
```

Comment: Ah, close, but a dialogue box every 10 seconds is pretty irritating. I'm looking for Applescript results-window like output, i.e., printing to the command line, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The return function should work.

```
    set stringYouWantToReturn to "banana"
return stringYouWantToReturn
```